# libgtk doesn't seem to be updating (3.18 found but 3.22 installed)

Tags: updates, gtk3, shared-library

I'm trying to compile a program (specifically, [Dino](https://github.com/dino/dino)), but I get the following error:

```
CMake Error at /usr/share/cmake-3.10/Modules/FindPackageHandleStandardArgs.cmake:137 (message):
  Could NOT find GTK3: Found unsuitable version "3.18.9", but required is at
  least "3.22" (found /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so)
```

I checked the file links; `libgtk-3.so` is a link to `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libgtk-3.so.0.2200.30`.

Basically, my program needs version `3.22` to compile, but is only finding version `3.18`. However, apt tells me the GTK version is indeed `3.22`:

```
hippo@tk-terbium:~$ apt-show-versions libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-dev
libgtk-3-0:amd64/bionic 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 uptodate
libgtk-3-0:i386 not installed
libgtk-3-dev:amd64/bionic 3.22.30-1ubuntu1 uptodate
libgtk-3-dev:i386 not installed
```

I tried reinstalling `libgtk-3-dev`, but got the same results. (I couldn't reinstall `libgtk-3-0` due to dependency issues). It seems like the library file is not getting updated even though the package is. Is there any way to update my `libgtk-3.so`?

***Note:*** I recently upgraded from 16.04 (Trusty) to 18.04 (Terbium). So I'm guessing my `libgtk-*` packages were upgraded and not freshly installed; maybe the older version didn't get replaced properly for some reason.

Comment: *I couldn't reinstall libgtk-3-0 due to dependency issues* - sounds like fixing that should be your focus

Comment: @steeldriver Thanks for the tip. I tried `sudo apt install --reinstall libgtk-3-0 libgtk-3-bin libgtk-3-common libgtk-3-dev` just now, didn't know I could do that. But unfortunately, it's still not working :(